# How to convert a Byte to a Bitstring in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, byte, bitstring

I have an ArrayList of Bytes. Firstly, when i print them i see integers? And the second thing is, i want to convert each Byte to a Bitstring and add it to a new list of bitstrings. How do i do that as there is no "i.toBitString"?

```
fun preprocessing() {

    val userInput = readLine()
    val charset = Charsets.UTF_8
    val bytearray = userInput?.toByteArray()
    var bitsets = ArrayList<BitSet>()
    if (bytearray != null) {
       // for(i in bytearray){
        //    bitsets.add(i.toBitset?)}

    }

}
```

preprocessing()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert to any base with this method, in your case this should work:

```
val userInput = "potatoes"
val bytearray = userInput.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
val bitsets = ArrayList<String>()

for (i in bytearray) {
    bitsets.add(i.toString(2))
}

bitsets.forEach { println(it) }
```

here is the docs:

```
/**
 * Returns a string representation of this [Byte] value in the specified [radix].
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException when [radix] is not a valid radix for number to string conversion.
 */
@SinceKotlin("1.1")
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public actual inline fun Byte.toString(radix: Int): String = this.toInt().toString(checkRadix(radix))
```